# When editing user questions, Stack Overflow warns that it might be spam

Tags: discussion, edits, spam

I recently tried to edit a user question, but I ended up quitting, because Stack Overflow wouldn't allow me to **Save Edit**. I originally thought the question needed improved formatting on some code and some corrections of English grammar.

The reason was because:

[image: Warning from Stack Overflow when Save Edit]

The original text was this:

> I use Alamofire to download multiple files on the tableViewCell show download progress.

From my point of view I believe it's pretty essential that the user says he's using "Alamofire Framework". Though he can include it using the tags and avoid it in the text.

**Question**:

Is it okay to edit an answer in that degree that you'll might end up changing too much information?

Should all references to e.g. frameworks be added to the question using tags, if so, should editors delete all sentences/rewrite to avoid references to these things?

Comment: Maybe it _was_ spam? Don't edit spam. I've lost track of which websites are known for spamming and which aren't, unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the spam block system.

Comment: I see it is marked as a duplicate. I will follow along with the other question. it should be discussed if code comments is allowed to be in different languages. And the spam detector should report better on the problem.

Comment: curious as to why that phrase is spam blocked. across over 40k confirmed spam posts I can't find a single instance of it or something like it being used.

Comment: @Magisch maybe a spammer rammed SE hard with obvious spam that was auto blocked, and contained that phrase as well? Shog did say in chat that LOTS of spam is being blocked automatically without ever reaching the site, what we see and flag is tiny bit of what is actually sent.